# Having trouble with type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my code:

```
fhand = open('romeo.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand: 
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in counts:
            counts[word] = 1
        else: 
            counts[word] += 1
```

I keep getting the error:

```
line 72, in <module>
  line = line.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using Python 3?  try `import sys; print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: Are you certain that you didn't assign a value to `str` somewhere above this code, like `str = "test value"` or such? For debugging purposes, you could put `print(repr(str), type(str))` before the line that causes the error.